# Create a new vector with text from strings in an old vector in R

Tags: r, regex

Working with a data frame in R studio. One column, `PODMap`, has sentences such as "At my property there is a house at 38.1234, 123.1234 and also I have a car". I want to create new columns, one for the latitude and one for the longitude.

`Fvalue` is the data frame. So far I have

```
matches <- regmatches(fvalue[,"PODMap"], regexpr("..\\.....", fvalue[,"PODMap"], perl = TRUE))
```

Since the only periods in the text are in longitude and latitude, this returns the first lat or long listed in each string (still working on finding a regex to grab the longitude from after the latitude but that's a different question). The problem is, for instance, if my vector is `c("test 38.1111", "x", "test 38.2222")` then it returns (38.1111. 38.2222) which has the right values, but the vector won't be the right length for my data frame and won't match. I need it to return a blank or a 0 or NA for each string that doesn't have the value matching the regular expression, so that it can be put into the data frame as a column. If I'm going about this entirely wrong let me know about that too.

Comment: What if you use `library(stringr)` and then `str_extract_all(x, "\\d+\\.\\d+")`? Or `str_match_all(x, "(\\d+\\.\\d+),\\s*(\\d+\\.\\d+)")`

Comment: To clarify there are some strings in PODMap, a column in a data frame, that does not have any lat & long coordinates? And when/if this arises you are hoping to not throw a wrench in your extraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexec`which returns a list of the same length so you don't loose the non-match spaces

```
PODMap<-c("At my property there is a house at 38.1234, 123.1234 and also I have a",
           "Test TEst TEST Tes T 12.1234, 123.4567 test Tes",
           "NO LONG HEre Here No Lat either",
           "At my property there is a house at 12.1234, 423.1234 and also I have ")

Index<-c(1:4)

fvalue<-data.frame(Index,PODMap)

matches <- regmatches(fvalue[,"PODMap"], regexec("..\\.....", fvalue[,"PODMap"], perl 
= TRUE))


> matches
[[1]]
[1] "38.1234"

[[2]]
[1] "12.1234"

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "12.1234"
```

Using the package `stringr`, we can get both the long and lat.

```
library(stringr)
matches<-str_match_all(fvalue[,"PODMap"], ".\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d\\d\\d")

> matches
[[1]]
     [,1]      
[1,] " 38.1234"
[2,] "123.1234"

[[2]]
     [,1]      
[1,] " 12.1234"
[2,] "123.4567"

[[3]]
     [,1]

[[4]]
     [,1]      
[1,] " 12.1234"
[2,] "423.1234"
```

The `\\d` checks for any digit 1:9, so that will keep out any words, and we use `str_match_all` to get all the matches from the string, as `regmatches` will only take the first match. `str_match_all` will set a value to NULL instead of character(0) though, which should not be a problem.

[Check out this regex demo](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I am working in a look-ahead regex so it will pull both the longitude and latitude as well, give me a couple min. And np!

Comment: That would be great chabo, my knowledge of regular expressions is extremely limited, hence the inelegant ..\\..... search for lat. Right now I was planning on using 1..\\....., since all the longitudes in my data are in the 100s